# How to consume an existing WCF service from my Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Im porting an "old" silverlight 3 app that used WS* webservices to connect. These services have been changed and are now replaced by an WCF "equivalent". I cant seem to get my silverlight app to work with the WCF service, I add a reference to the: http.....svc and create my client, but the clientConfiguration is empty. The silverlight app doesnt know the datatypes given in the WCF service... all this is working well in the WPF client also using them...

All i seem to get on one of my types from the WCF service is a public variable called "data"... anyone know what this is?

Sincerely,

Comment: More information would help :) The data types are usually defined by the service. What do you get when you view your service reference with Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF for silverlight support a subset of bindings for normal WCF. As the time of siverlight4, we support basic http binding, nettcp binding and pollingduplex binding. For nettcp binding, it has some port restriction and requires you setup some policy server. You can find more details on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571(VS.95).aspx

HTH